# Using neural networks for classification in Hierarchical data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, hierarchical-data-format

I am stuck in a problem wherein I have hierarchical data, say $A->B->C$(smaller to biggest), and the smallest unit of data is a block(A consists of multiple blocks, B consists of multiple A's, and C consists of multiple B's), and I want to classify blocks into labels.

Now the block labels for each group of A is independent of block labels for another group of A, however the "trends or patterns" followed by data could be similar and that is what is to be learnt.

The complexity I am facing is variable input sizes. I cannot possibly train single neural networks for groups of A, since its a large number. So, I am thinking in terms of groups at level B, but how could I create a scheme which could handle these variable input sizes.

Each block is represented by a one dimensional array of the total number of labels in the group of A it belongs to.Also, I have the information for hierarchy for every block(smallest unit) possible. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!